# open a page in an iframe

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, iframe

i am trying to incorporate the following html with apex code

```
<a href="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))}{!myAttachment.ContentId}" 
   target="demo_iframe" style="white-space:normal;color: #00f; text-decoration: underline"  >
  File: {!myAttachment.Attachment}</a> <br></br>

<iframe name="demo_iframe" width="1200" height="400"></iframe>
```

There is the link, if we click on the link, a new tab opens. I am trying to open the tab in the iframe. But this code is not working. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.